# Using reduce with a composite key in couchdb view returns no result on GET

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have a couchdb view with the following map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.date_of_operation) {
    date_triple = doc.date_of_operation.split("/");
    d = new Date(date_triple[2], date_triple[1]-1, date_triple[0], 0, 0, 0, 0)
    emit([d, doc.name], 1);
  }
}
```

When I issue a GET request for this, I get the whole view's data (2.8MB):

```
$ curl -X GET http://somehost:5984/ops-db/_design/ops-views/_view/counts

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2751k    0 2751k    0     0  67456      0 --:--:--  0:00:41 --:--:--  739k
```

However, when I add a reduce function:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

I no longer get any data when using curl:

```
$ curl -X GET http://somehost:5984/ops-db/_design/ops-views/_view/counts

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    42    0    42    0     0   7069      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8400
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":27065}
]}
```

This view & map & reduce functions were added using the Futon interface and when the Reduce checkbox is checked there, I do get one row for every 'date, name' pairs with values accumulated for that pair. What changes when queried through a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calling the view through curl you can try passing in the necessary parameters for triggering the reduce and grouping

e.g.

Explicitly tell CouchDB to run the `reduce` function

`$ curl -X GET http://somehost:5984/ops-db/_design/ops-views/_view/counts?reduce=true`

Or the `group` and `group_level` params

You can read more on the available options [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) (under `Querying Options` section)

Comment: Thanks, adding group=true to query params solved the problem!

Comment: @Prakash Kindly mark as answer if this solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce should look like this

```
_sum
```

So a simple "view" would look like this:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/foo",
   "_rev": "2-6145338c3e47cf0f311367a29787757c",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "test1": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n  emit(null, 1);\n}",
           "reduce": "_sum"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: There was no change using _sum, had to add group=true to query params.